# WordPress .htaccess not working for rewriterule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Can we rewrite WordPress page `/ghij` to show the contents of page `/faq`, when permalinks are already enabled?

My page is `example.com?page_id=70&category=Footage`. After enabling permalink it is showing `example.com/video-category?category=Footage`. I want it to look like `example.com/category/Footage`.

Any help in this will be appreciated.

Current `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: show your `.htaccess` code.

Comment: right now it is having basic wordpress .htaccess code 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: I used RewriteRule ^category/Footage/$ ?page_id=70&category=Footage [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/Footage/$ video-category?category=Footage [QSA,L] But it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=([0-9]*)&category=(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Works. And redirects from:
http://test.com/index.php?page_id=70&category=Footage 
To:
http://test.com/70/Footage

**UPDATED:**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?page_id=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

This rule Works and makes **inner redirect** (without url change) from:
http://test.com/70/Footage
To:
http://test.com/index.php?page_id=70&category=Footage

Comment: Yes it is working, but I want rewrite url. I mean in browser I want it as domain.com/ghij but page shold show content of faq page

Comment: @Pankajjarial ty out this one.

Comment: thanks a lot it is working but it is not showing the content of http://test.com/index.php?page_id=70&category=Footage under http://test.com/70/Footage only URL is getting changed. I want http://test.com/70/Footage to show in browser as url, and get the content of http://test.com/index.php?page_id=70&category=Footage. Thanks for being concerned.

Comment: @Pankajjarial how works that redirect? 1. first `RewriteRule`make 301 redirection to `/70/Footage`. Second rule - with this ulr executes `index.php`. So.. it isnt valid url by WordPress. You must define (make valid) that urls in your wordpress admin panel.

Comment: @Pankajjarial so now seems like yor task is: "from `/page_id/category/` show me `index.php?page_id=X&catgeory=Y`"... But i make this (from your Question): "I want it to look like `example.com/category/Footage`". So now it looks like it, doesnt it? :)

Comment: yes you are right. My task is is: "from /page_id/category/ show me index.php?page_id=X&catgeory=Y" :D Actually I am opening index.php?page_id=X&catgeory=Y page. Only Url should get changed to /page_id/category/, content should remain the same. But since permalink is enabled it is showing something like /category?category=Footage

Comment: notice. u got 2 rules now "in" and "out" short url. now just edit your WP posts permalinks properly from Admin Panel.

Answer (score 0):

i hope the following plugin will help you more

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-editor/

please check this plugin it will rewrite the permalink as you want without any coding knowledge.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My work is done. yes this plugin can be helpful.